# bulk upgrade *.doc to *.docx

Tags: conversion, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2013, bulk

I have a several directories that contain maybe 400-500 resumes that are a mixed bag of doc and docx

I would like to get all the office documents up to docx  is there a way to bulk convert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed - microsoft has released a utility which can do bulk upgrades of documents from doc to docx.

[take a look at this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/19/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx.aspx) to find out more along with download links to the app[ and the prerequisite installer (office compatibility pack)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: brilliant, glad to hear.

Comment: actually one small snag. It doesn't "replace" the file like convert in word does for my first job (the one that drove this question) it was just a huge root dir and no sub directory but now I have a task that has LOTS of sub folders so i need a good inline replace option.  I might make some sort of script to feed each job as a single job and change the config file on the fly. if you have a better suggestion I would love to hear it

Comment: I have noticed that the tool in that link is in the category of Office 2007. But if I use Word 2013 to open some docxes created under Word 2007, there is still a convert option. So I'm wondering is there a tool that can bulk convert old files to the newest version?